# No Internet (Ethernet r8169 driver) after suspend

Tags: networking, internet, dell, ethernet

Ok. So I'm pretty sure this issue started after coming back from a suspend, which I understand is common in Ubuntu 14. Right now I don't know where to start troubleshooting. Everything seems fine, my network manager is listed as connected. I can ping to localhost but not to anything online.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 17 5000 series. My wireless driver is r8169.

Comment: I've noticed you haven't flagged any answers as solution. Has the problem been fixed? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

Work-around for 14.04:

Create the following Bourne shell script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`:

```sh
MYNAME=$0

restart_ethernet() {
   /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_ethernet(r8169) BEGIN'
   /sbin/modprobe -v -r r8169
   /sbin/modprobe -v r8169
   /usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'restart_ethernet(r8169) END'
}

/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'case=[' ${1} ']'
case "${1}" in
   hibernate|suspend) ;;
   resume|thaw) restart_ethernet;;
esac
```

That should force the r8169 driver to resume Ethernet service after resuming from suspend.

Make sure that the script is executable (`chmod +x`).

Answer (score 0):

You should (almost) always be able to ping localhost, as this is your own computer, if you cannot there is usually something wrong with your stack.

First check to see what you are connected to with

`ifconfig`

Next try these to restart. (you may need to do `sudo` before these commands)

If you see `eth0` or any `ethX` where 'X' is number (ethernet/wired) do:

> `ifdown eth0`
>
> `ifup eth0`

If you see `wlan0` or any `wlanX` where 'X' is number (wireless) do:

> `ifdown wlan0`
>
> `ifup wlan0`

This basically sets your card down, then up. If that doesn't work there are other steps.

Comment: I saw eth0 and wlan0, but i still got back responses, "Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0"

Comment: @user1622727 the eth0 is if you are connected using a wired network interface card, the wlan0 would be if you are using wireless network interface card.

Comment: I got that, and both are listed with ifconfig (sorry i can't paste that result), but yeah, nothing happened except for those responses "ignoring unknown..." when i ran the commands you gave me

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. You have to restart network manager:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

There is bug for this issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd-shim/+bug/1184262